# Create new post

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a blog website and I have New Post button

this is my post list function

```
def PostList(request):
 post_list = Post.objects.all()

 context = {'post_list' : post_list}
 return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

this is my post detail function

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post_detail = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    context = {'post_detail' : post_detail}
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

and I want to create this function but I dont know how

```
def post_new(request):
    post_new = Post.objects.get()
```

Can anyone help me I am new to django

Comment: Please take a look at the [*modelforms* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/ try this